# Python Requests response decode

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-requests

I send a request using python requests and then print the response, what confuse me is that the Chinese characters in response is something like **\u6570\u636e\u8fd4\u56de\u6210\u529f**
Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import requests

url = "http://www.biyou888.com/api/getdataapi.php?ac=3005&sess_token=&urlid=-1"
res = requests.get(url)
if res.status_code == 200:
    print res.text
```

Below is the response

[response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXAXl.png)

What should i do to tranfer the response? I have try to use encode and decode but it dose work.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer the response"? What does not work?

Comment: I mean convert the "/u" format charracters into Chinese characters

Answer (score 5):

Use requests.Response.json and you will get the chinese caracters.

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://www.biyou888.com/api/getdataapi.phpac=3005&sess_token=&urlid=-1"
res = requests.get(url)
if res.status_code == 200:
    res_payload_dict = res.json()
    print(res_payload_dict)
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work, you get an error? The json you have is not the right one? Just edited the 3rd line that was broken.

Comment: There is  no "?" between host and parameters in your code, I fix it but the result is something like this
 
    {u'status': 1, u'info': u'\u6570\u636e\u8fd4\u56de\u6210\u529f', ...}

Comment: I am using Python 3, that must be the reason of our difference, I will try with python 2

Comment: Thx, I have found the reason why the response  text is not Chinese characters by deault,  it's because the response return "/u" format Letters, Instead of characters encoded using utf-8

Comment: Testing the code with python 2 and printing `res_payload_dict['info']`, I got 数据返回成功. Encoding is still puzzling to me to say the least. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### How to use response.encoding using Python requests?

For illustrate, let’s ping API of Github.

```py
# import requests module 
import requests 
  
# Making a get request 
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com') 
  
# print response 
print(response) 
  
# print encoding of response 
print(response.encoding)
```

output:

```sh
<Response [200]>
utf-8
```

So, in your example, try `res.json()` instead of `res.text`?

As in:

```py
# encoding of your response 
print(res.encoding)

res.encoding='utf-8-sig'
print(res.json())
```

`sig` in `utf-8-sig` is the abbreviation of `signature` (i.e. signature utf-8 file).

Using `utf-8-sig` to read a file will treat BOM as file info instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://www.biyou888.com/api/getdataapi.php?ac=3005&sess_token=&urlid=-1"
res = requests.get(url)
res_dict = {}
if res.status_code == 200:
    print type(res.text)
    print res.text
    res_dict = json.loads(res.text)  # get a dict from parameter string

    print "Dict:"
    print type(res_dict)
    print res_dict
    print res_dict['info']
```

Use `json` module to parse that input. And the prefix `u` just means it is a unicode string. When you use them, the `u` prefix won't affect, just like what I show at the last several lines.

Comment: I tried your way , But only the last line print Chinese character

Comment: The 'u' prefix won't bother when you really use the response text. And if you just want to *print* the Chinese characters out, like my `print` demo shows, use something like `print res_dict['data'][0]['title']`.