# Python requests library call works on Windows but not Linux... WHY?

Tags: python, json, linux, web-scraping, python-requests

Long time user of python requests here.  Trying to do a simple call to this endpoint:
`https://www.overstock.com/api/product.json?prod_id=10897789`

My current code:

```
import requests

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept': 'application/json' }
url = 'https://www.overstock.com/api/product.json?prod_id=10897789'
r = requests.get( url, headers=headers )
result = r.json()
print( result )
```

Expected outcome (shortened):

```
{'categoryId': 244, 'subCategoryId': 31446, 'altSubCategoryId': 0, 'taxonomy': {'store': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rugs', 'apiUrl': 'https://www.overstock.com/api/search.json?taxonomy=sto1', 'htmlUrl': 'https://www.overstock.com/Home-Garden/1/store.html'}, 'department': {'id': 3, 'name': 'Casual Rugs'...
```

Unfortunately, from that same script on Linux, I am not getting the identical result.  So far I am stumped as to why this is happening...

Here is the ugly Linux error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/online-project-7j1lNF7P/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

**What could possibly be the issue?  Here's what else I tried...**

1. <strike>Linux is NOT running python 3.6 but instead running 2.7x to execute requests.</strike>
2. <strike>Adding 'Accept': 'application/json' to headers will surely solve this</strike>
3. <strike>**decode** the data variable first data = response.decode()</strike> ([link to SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880914/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value)) Fail: "AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'decode'"
4. <strike>Use requests.Response.json</strike> ([link to SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818881/python-requests-response-decode)) Fail: Gives same error as above.
5. <strike>Upgrading to python 3.9.9 may solve it.</strike> Nope!  This still fails for me.
6. <strike>Perhaps it's your firewall.</strike> Nope, checked `ufw` and it's `Status: inactive`

#5 Error (on a new Linux machine, upgraded python to 3.9.9):

```
`$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

@balmy - Here is the output I'm  getting after confirming requests version 2.26.0 AND python 3.9...

```
$ python3 test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test_scripts/test3.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

@JCaesar - here is the text (shortened to the part I think is relevant which appears bot detection is in play perhaps)

```
        <div id="bd">
            <div class="ohNoRedBar">
                There was an error processing your request.
            </div>
            <span class="ohNoText"></span>
        </div>
```

@Philippe - here is the result in response to your comment 'Can you change the print statement to `print(r.text)` and run `python3 test3.py | jq .`'...

```
$ sudo python3 test3.py | jq .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/test_scripts/test3.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(r.text)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

@Philippe - answer to your next comment
`$ sudo python3 test3.py | jq . parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 10 Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Please let me know if you have a solution.  Thank you!

Comment: After the *get* add r.raise_for_status(). I suspect that you're not getting the HTTP 200 you hoped for. You're not currently making any kind of check - you just assume that the *get* will work

Comment: @JCaesar I just re-ran with `r.raise_for_status()` but it returned nothing.  :(  Perhaps I am encountering some form of bot detection? idk...

Comment: See my answer below. It may help

Comment: works fine for me. python 3.9

Comment: but as stated by jcaesar, this error is a sign that you didn't get ok response. check that first

Comment: @diggusbickus You ran the above code in Linux and it worked for you?  BTW I am also on python 3.9.  What did you do differently?  Also, after running r.raise_for_status() it did not give any output.

Comment: no you're on 3.6

Comment: @diggusbickus gah, maybe you're right.  I did try  to upgrade to 3.9 but not sure why it's showing that 3.6.  Check this... `root@online-pro:~/online-project#  . /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/online-project-7j1lNF7P/bin/activate
(online-project) root@online-pro:~/online-project# python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)`

Comment: I note that he question has been edited to indicate that Python 3.9.9 is now in play. However, we do not see anything to indicate checks for the HTTP status code

Comment: I also doubt any kind of bot detection issue as that would very likely lead to a 403 error

Comment: Have you looked at the response you’re actually getting (which obviously isn’t JSON) by instead of calling `.json()` on it print or save r.content or r.text to file. Chances are it’s your firewall.

Comment: If it was a firewall issue surely you wouldn't expect to get HTTP 200

Comment: @balmy Firewall, hmm.  For Linux, I previously used `ufw` but after running `ufw status` I got `Status: inactive`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the request module? Add *print(requests.__version__)* to your code. That should emit 2.26.0. If not, update requests and try again

Comment: I repeat: What actual data are you getting back? That will most likely explain where things are going wrong.

Comment: @JCaesar it's requests version `2.26.0`

Comment: OK - So you've tested the HTTP status code and it returns 200. Now, as has been said more than once, *print(r.text)* to see what you've got. It's possible that you'll see an HTML page with some detail about what's gone wrong.

Comment: @balmy I put the output in the original question.

Comment: @JCaesar will  do and post in original question.

Comment: That’s the exception resulting from calling r.json() when it isn’t getting JSON to decode. What is r.content which is bytes or r.text which is str? I.e. what is the actual response to the GET.

Comment: @JCaesar the html was huge but I did find relevant things which I put in original question.

Comment: @balmy sorry the html was too huge to post so I posted the relevant thing in the html which indicates there was `an error processing your request.`

Comment: @JCaesar man, this is making me think I have to switch over to Splash, Selenium or Cypress to get this.  Was hoping to avoid but my scraping servers are all Linux.

Comment: There has to be a rational explanation, it’s due to a difference in the request. Maybe on Windows a proxy is adding that ‘Accept-Encoding’ that JCaesar spotted. You may need to spy the full HTTP GET and response - on Window you could use .e.g Telerik Fiddler classic with https interception enabled - you’re trying to log the full http GET and response, including headers, cookie, data. Then do the same on Linux maybe with mitm. Then you compare the two interactions.. This is simplest by sorting the headers on request/response into alphabetical order.

Comment: @balmy Telerik seems amazing but it’s a paid service.  I may go that way if I can’t solve it soon.

Comment: Fiddler Classic is free. Download and it’s a local install. No registration required.

Comment: Can you change the `print` statement to `print(r.text)` and run `python3 test3.py | jq .` ?

Comment: @Philippe - answered, looks like I got a weird error about `Broken pipe` and `apt_pkg` not being installed so I'll try to solve those, unless that was what you were getting at...

Comment: The error messages are quite strange. Can you install `jq` from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ ?

Comment: @Philippe ok I have installed jq and posted result in original answer

Comment: Now you can do `python3 test3.py | xclip` , and paste result to https://paste-bin.xyz/

Comment: @JCaesar it is solved, thank you for your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all due to being IP blocked.

Here is ultimately the script that saved the day...

```
import requests

url = "https://www.overstock.com/api/product.json?prod_id=10897789"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}

http_proxy  = "http://ip:port"
https_proxy = "http://ip:port"

proxyDict = {
              "http"  : http_proxy,
              "https" : https_proxy
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
result = r.json()
print(result)
```

Thank you all for the group effort!

After seeing this worked for @JCaesar, @diggusbickus, @balmy, and @Philippe I realized that the only remaining stone unturned was the ip address.  By adding rotating residential proxy IPs, I made the request and got the data immediately.

Thanks to @JCaesar for revealing `'Accept-Encoding'` for without that, it would not work at all.  Thank you to @diggusbickus for your comment of `walrus notation :=` for without that I would have assumed Python 3.9.x was running and upgrading that.

Answer (score 1):

Running *requests* 2.26.0 on macOS 12.0.1 and Python 3.9.9 I discovered that the website **requires** Accept-Encoding in the headers. This works as expected for me:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}


with requests.Session() as session:
    (r := session.get('https://www.overstock.com/api/product.json?prod_id=10897789', headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
    print(r.json())
```

Comment: Trying to run your code but it's constantly giving error with the indented block: `  File "test.py", line 12
    (r := session.get('https://www.overstock.com/api/product.json?prod_id=10897789', headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @rom if you're on python3.6 you won't be able to use walrus notation `:=` and you don't need to raise anything. status code is just `r.status_code` (and reason is `r.reason`)

Comment: @diggusbickus currently trying to upgrade my python to 3.9.  I'm using a `pipenv` virtual environment so I'm trying to figure out how to upgrade that.  It must have avoided using that, idk...

Comment: maybe the `accept-encoding` is really all you need. in my requests version this header is sent automatically, maybe it's not done in yours. you can check the headers you sent by printing `r.request.headers`

Comment: @JCaesar certainly your script works for me after testing it in Windows but, unfortunately, even after upgrading to Python 3.9.9 on Linux, I still get an error and I pasted your code directly into a script on Ubuntu.   :(   I'm still not giving up...

Comment: What error did you see in 3.9.9? Perhaps best if you update your original question

Comment: @JCaesar updated, please see the error in the original question.  This is maddening!  Your script has worked on everything I've tested except in Linux